# Database entity exposed as object in WCF service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4

I have a WCF service in which I have a method which returns an IQueryable of an object representing a database table (Accommodation) using Entity Framework.  When I try and use that method on the client side the method does not return IQueryable but object.  I looked at the code for the service and the Accommodation class that Entity Framework generates has this attribute

```
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
```

So, AFAIK the client should be able to see that class.  What is going wrong here?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type will only appear in the metadata if it is used on the contract. The metadata has no idea what IQueryable is - its a definition of behavior whereas the contract only defines state so the generated code will use somethingit does understand in this situation - i.e. object

It is really not a good idea to use the EF generated types on your service contract - you, in effect, tightly couple your service consumers to your data access layer. Use EF internally in the service and use types which define the data you want to pass around on the service boundary

Comment: The only issue with using types that define the data is that that data will be exactly the same as the data I want to pass around plus the table that I want to pass around has links to other tables and I want to pass that around to so what I will have as a result is a whole LOT of left right assignments for very little benefit.